# VBA: Rename Excel sheet name to match a date format from 08082023 to 08-08-2023

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Exported excel file from Google sheets and now the naming of the sheets(tabs) are stripped off a backslash "/".

```
Before: 08/08/2023
After: 08082023
Desired, since "/" not allowed: 08-08-2023
```

Could this be done using a VBA construct?
I don't know anything about VBA, just trying to piece something together.

Any help is much apreaciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you could have a function like this which you could run (F5) as a one-off exercise

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, str As String
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then
    str = Left$(ws.Name, 2) & "-" & Mid$(ws.Name, 3, 2) & "-" & Right(ws.Name, 4)
    ws.Name = str
End If
```

Next

Answer (score 2):

Put the following code in a module (eg of your personal workbook)-

```
Sub renameSheetsOfActiveWorkbook()
    renameSheets ActiveWorkbook
End Sub


Sub renameSheets(wb As Workbook)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Len(ws.Name) >= 8 And IsNumeric(Left(ws.Name, 8)) Then
            ws.Name = Left(ws.Name, 2) _
                    & "-" & Mid(ws.Name, 3, 2) _
                    & "-" & Mid(ws.Name, 5, 4) _
                    & Mid(ws.Name, 9)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The Sub `renameSheets` will rename all sheets (if the name is at least 8 chars long and is numeric) for a given Workbook. You could for example use this Sub in a Loop that opens all related workbooks in a folder.

The Sub `renameSheetsOfActiveWorkbook` will call that routine for the Active Workbook. It has no parameter and therefore you can call it from the Macro menu of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't touched VBA for a while, but here is my two cents:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "########" Then ws.Name = Format(ws.Name, "00-00-0000")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the thing! I had mixed up values with 8, 7 and 6 total in length, so this sorted it out. And followed up with a formatting such as "For Each sh In Worksheets: sh.Name = Format(sh.Name, "MM-DD-YYYY"): Next sh"